# What's the difference between vmware linked clone vs snapshot

Tags: vmware-workstation

What's the difference between taking snapshot in vmware and linked clone? which one is better for performance? why do I choose one and not the other"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a virtual machine and want to save the state (before doing some changes) and be able to restore the state: choose a snapshot

You have a virtual machine and want to make a copy of it (with minimum disk space used) and want to work with the original 'and' the copy: choose a linked clone

Linkes clones are also using snapshots. Working with two linked-cloned-machines running will cause a higher load on the host, so it may be slower.

So if you don't need more copies running at the same time use snapshots and this will be the fastest way.

Comment: Thanks boboes, so if I have a VM machine that contains a server and am doing a development on that server, and it consumes memory and cpu, so do I take a snapshot each time I want to install service pack for the product on the VM or patches? or do I make a new linked clone? which choice will be the more efficient?

Comment: Snapshot, because you dont't need to run two instances of the server at the same time. (Check out also features like persistent disks. May be helpfull when having data that should be kept after restoring a snapshot)

Comment: How will a linked clone run 2 instances? If a linked clone runs will it run the template machine?

Comment: You can run the original machine and every clone you created from. The clone has the state, the original machine had, when jou cloned  it. (If my answer was helpful, jou may want do accept it.)

Comment: Yep, I accept it and +1, but still confused, that didn't answer the question in my comment, if you have linked clone and you turn on the cloned machine, will it require the template machine to be turned on?

Comment: Sorry, missunderstood your question. No, the clone can run autonomus.

Comment: Great, appreciate your explanation.